# Python Zeep - how to set attributes for element

Tags: python-2.7, zeep

I have request like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:...>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <con:getRequest>
         <header requestId="?" usageMode="?">
            <systemName>?</systemName>
            <timestamp>?</timestamp>
            <userName>?</userName>
         </header>
         <body>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <fetchProperty>
               <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
               <propertyName>?</propertyName>
            </fetchProperty>
            <id>?</id>
         </body>
      </con:getRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How I can set params in  ??

I set other values like below but I have no idea how to set those attributes.

```
self.__client.service.get(
            header=dict(
            systemName=system_name,
            timestamp=datetime.date(2018, 04, 26),
            userName=system_username),
            body=dict(fetchProperty=dict(propertyName='ALL'), id=agreement_id)
        )
```

Anyone can help with that?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

```
self.__client.get(
            header={
                'requestId':'123',
                'usageMode':'normal',
                'systemName': system_name,
                'timestamp': datetime.date(2018, 04, 26),
                'userName': system_username
            },
            body=dict(fetchProperty=dict(propertyName='ALL'), id=agreement_id)
        )
```

I don't know why if I put those parameters in dict() methot it didn't work